# Fonts doesn`t work in react after using react router

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, parsing, fonts, font-face

yesterday I wanted to create a landingpage for a subcategory if my website. The site it build with create react app. I created the sub-page using react router. On lokal machine everything works fine.
But after I deployed it on AWS (amplify) the included fonts in the whole app (old site and new one) are not working anymore.

I am getting the "Failed to decode downloaded font: " and "OTS parsing error: invalid version tag" errors.

I didn't changes anything in the index.scss/index.html files.
After I`m running the build command the fonts-files are in the right folder ...

This is how my index.scss looks like:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "SF Compact Display";
src: url("./assets/fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Regular.otf");
 }
@font-face {
font-family: "SF Compact Display Semi";
src: url("./assets/fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Semibold.otf");
}
```

I also tried it with absolute path :

```
enter code here  src: url("assets/fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Semibold.otf");
```

But it doesn't work.
I imported the index.scss into my index.tsx `import './index.scss'`

Both files are living in the src root.

I have read lots of other stories that are similar to my problem. But nothing works.

Does anyone have a guess why I am getting this problem? Is there maybe a redirecting issue with aws as this is the only think which I changed?
(as i said before I included the react router the fonts where working fine ). I also tried to remove the react router and get the old page with the right fonts. But now I have the same issue there.

On aws rewrites I included `</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|json|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|otf)$)([^.]+$)/>` with /index.html and 200 Rewrite.

Im trying to fix it for hours now, but I don't have any clue what the issue could be.

I hope anyone had the same issue in the past and can help me.

Bests

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you already solved this, but here're some thoughts to help.

The `Failed to decode downloaded font` error is almost certainly because the app responded to the browser's request for the font with html. This would likely happen if there's a catch-all route configured for the SPA (e.g. respond with the root index page or a not-found page).

From the info you've shared, the most likely issue is that the relative path to the font files is being broken in the build process. The key insight here is that `url("assets/fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Semibold.otf");` isn't actually an absolute path because it's missing the `/` prefix. If your build's putting the font file in  `/assets/fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Semibold.otf`, what you want is: `url("/assets/fonts/SF-Compact-Display-Semibold.otf");`.

A useful way to check the directory structure produced by building is to run `npm run build` (see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/). This produces a production build in a directory called `build`. When creating an AWS Amplify project, it automatically sets up running the build process for you (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html). By default, for `create react app` apps, this means it'll do `npm run build` prior to deploy.

Comment: The answer is just perfect. I have been looking for this information for weeks!! Thanks